# I can't install npm after using curl to install nodejs 6.x

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, curl, npm

I was trying to install nodejs 5.x on my Elementary OS freya computer. I followed this link https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ but I forgot to change 6.x to 5.x on this command:
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
After this mistake I ran that command but changing 6.x to 5.x.
And then I tried to install as the link says:
    sudo apt-get install nodejs
When I checked nodejs version it says 6.3 version. I don't want this version, I want 5.12 and now I can't undo this. Furthermore when I try to install npm it says:
    npm: Depends: nodejs but it is not going to install

Please I'm desesperate! And sorry but English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Also sorry for the commands but I'm new at posting here. This was the command: 'curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -'

Comment: Why do you want 5.x? I don't think it's receiving any more updates at this point. You should transition to 6.x, the latest "current" branch.

Comment: I am working with ionic & I've had no problem with 5.x version. I don't know if 6.x works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to test or switch between different version of node, use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Here is a small script for easy install :

```
# Usage   : ./nvm_install.sh <node_version>
# Example : ./nvm_install.sh 5
# reinstall nvm & install node with version <node_version>
######################################
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf ~/.nvm
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf ~/.bower
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.profile

source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm_version=`nvm --version`

echo "nvm version ${nvm_version}"

NODE_VERSION=5

if [ -n "$1" ];
then
    NODE_VERSION="$1"
fi

echo "Installing node v$NODE_VERSION"

# install node 5
nvm install $NODE_VERSION
nvm use $NODE_VERSION
node -v
nvm ls
```

You may need to logout/login after executing this script